# Is it possible to set the terminal emulator used by desktop configuration files?

Tags: .desktop, terminator, octave

I have Octave 4.0.0 installed on my PC (which isn't available in the software centre btw or any PPAs I'm aware of, I installed it from source) and my preferred way to use it is via the command-line interface (CLI). Hence I have created a desktop configuration file (`/usr/share/applications/octave-cli.desktop`) for it with the following contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=GNU Octave (CLI)
Comment=Scientific Computing using GNU Octave
TryExec=/usr/local/bin/octave-cli
Exec=octave --no-gui
Icon=/usr/local/share/octave/4.0.0/imagelib/octave-logo.svg
Terminal=true
Type=Application
StartupNotify=false
MimeType=text/x-octave;text/x-matlab;
NoDisplay=false
Categories=Math;Science;
```

Now the reason I'm asking this question is I'd like to know if there's anyway to set the terminal emulator used when launching this application, such that it does not change according to my desktop environment. If you would like a specific example (of a terminal emulator, that is) to use in your answer try terminator (found at `/usr/share/applications/terminator.desktop`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this desktop file and, as example, `xterm` as terminal emulator:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=GNU Octave (CLI)
Comment=Scientific Computing using GNU Octave
TryExec=/usr/local/bin/octave-cli
Exec=xterm -e "octave --no-gui"
Icon=/usr/local/share/octave/4.0.0/imagelib/octave-logo.svg
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=false
MimeType=text/x-octave;text/x-matlab;
NoDisplay=false
Categories=Math;Science;
```

---

**Explanation:**

- `Exec=xterm -e "octave --no-gui"`

  We use `xterm` as terminal emulator
- If you need another shell, use the line below

  `Exec=xterm -e "/bin/bash -c 'octave --no-gui'"`
- `Terminal=false`

  We don't need another terminal, because we start a terminal emulator via `Exec=`